# Receiving error "name 'urllib' is not defined" when using urllib.parse despite including "import urllib.parse"

Tags: python, youtube-api, urllib

I receive the error "name 'urllib' is not defined" when using urllib.parse despite including "import urllib.parse" at the top of my code. The error occurs when using the "search" function in the [youtube data api](https://youtube-data-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/youtube_api.html).

My code is as follows

```
from youtube_api import YouTubeDataAPI
import urllib.parse

api_key = # actual api key inserted here
yt = YouTubeDataAPI(api_key)

search = yt.search(location = (2.09319, 96.647463), \
                        locationRadius = "50km", \
                        order_by = "viewCount", \
                        topic_id = "/m/06bvp", \
                        max_results = 5)
```

The output should be similar to as outlined on [this page](https://youtube-data-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/quickstart.html#quickstart)

I receive the following error:
[error with urllib not being defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxLCg.png)

How can this be happening if I've included "import urllib.parse"? I've also tried "import urllib" and have the same issue.

Comment: The error suggests the missing import is in the youtube_api library, not your code. Looks to me like a bug in the search when `location` is supplied (nothing else in the module tries to use `urllib` like this): https://github.com/SMAPPNYU/youtube-data-api/blob/master/youtube_api/youtube_api.py

Comment: [The repository you are relying on](https://github.com/SMAPPNYU/youtube-data-api) doesn't seem to be updated anymore...

Comment: `urllib.parse` is only one submodule of `urllib`. Did you try to import the others as well?